# Which rule allows me to prevent duplicate insert by email/id on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've been looking on the docs but I couldn't figure out how to prevent duplicated entries if the email exist on a record. There are my current rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with an email and password
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my record format is:

[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this type of query in firebase due to it's distributed nature. In general, arrays are extremely tricky and you can read about their limitations in the context of Firebase [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

The way I see it you have two options, you can index your users "array" by the email itself, or you can keep a completely separate object holding all the emails in the system to check against when you make an insert. My suggestion would be the first, set the user object to `users/<email>`.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing that.....how do I do it?......I have a facebook login as well aside that mail/password login, I just have a local postgres database where I update a facebook_id field, it's separated from that custom users table in the firebase server, will your solution of putting the email as the index will affect the facebook login?. Thanks

Comment: It is completely up to you when you actually do the check, but all you need to do is something like `ref.child('emails').child(email_address).set(true)` as soon someone signs up and then you can add a security rule to check if `ref.child(emails/<address).exists()` to disallow the read or write. So for instance you might want to set this every time a facebook user signs in, or an email/pass user signs up

Comment: wait, I just want to put the email as the index, how do I do that please?....I'm a noob on these OAuth systems.....I'm not interested in that emails array, just want the email as the pk.....will this solution cause a performance issue then the database grow larger?....

Comment: The idea is that you just do something like `ref.child('users/'+email_address).set({name: 'bob'})` instead of using it like an array. Then you can just check if `users/<email>` exists in your security rules. You're going to need to do some tutorials if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: could you point me out some tutorial?. I understand the first part of creating one array for each email, I just don't know how to check in the security rules if that email array exist....If you tell me how that rule is written then my problem is solved....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118363/discussion-between-juan-and-tommybananas).